# Associations: One to Many Relationship, How to Return to the One from Many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, associations

I have a simple website where I show recipes from cookbooks.

Every cookbook has many recipes.

My question: how do I link the user back to the correct cookbook page from the recipe page?  How would I direct a user who is viewing a recipe with `id` 4 back to cookbook with `id` 2?

Cookbook Controller:

```
class CookbookController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @cookbooks = Cookbook.all
    end

    def show
    @cookbook = Cookbook.find(params[:id])
    @recipes = @cookbook.recipes
    end
end
```

Recipe Controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Cookbook Model:

```
class Cookbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
end
```

Recipe Model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cookbook
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/' => redirect('/cookbooks')

  get '/cookbooks' => 'cookbooks#index'
  get '/cookbooks/:id' => 'cookbooks#show', as: :cookbook

  get '/recipe/:id' => 'recipes#show', as: :recipe
end
```

Up until now I have been using:

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

but this isn't a permanent solution.

I followed the Rails Guide on Routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and I have tried the following (and received the following errors):

```
<%= link_to "Back", cookbook_path(@cookbook) %>
```

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cookbooks", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

```
<%= link_to "Back", cookbook_path(@cookbook.id) %>
```

> undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

And other solutions that either raised errors/exceptions or worked with the recipe `id` instead of the cookbook `id`.

I have also tried to allow for the Recipe Controller to inherit from the Cookbook Controller in order to get the `id` for the cookbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track (no pun intended) when you attempted to use the Cookbook Controller with `cookbook_path`.

Each recipe stores the `id` of its respective cookbook with the one-to-many relationship you defined in both of your Models.

As such, we can utilize this simple `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Back", cookbook_path(@recipe.cookbook.id) %>
```